# Accessing DOM elements react JS

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I am new to react JS. I'm using react JS in conjunction with an existing Rails app. 
With the help of webpacker gem i have all the dependencies available.

For some reason DOM elements are not available to react JS. In tutorials the same thing works fine.
In an html.erb file i have

```
<div id='root' data-link='https://x.com'></div>
```

app/javascript/index.js file

```
const root = document.querySelector('#root')
ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard link={root.dataset.link} />, root)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
```

Also, is it possible without the use of Refs or Portals that I can have above working.

Comment: How is your document structured? If you open up the Developer Tools and check Elements, is there a div with id `root` where it should be?

Comment: yes it's there, even when i run `const root = document.querySelector('#root')
` code on browser console, i see the dom object appearing.. but for some reason react JS can't find it

Comment: Is your script loaded at the bottom of the body tag? It might be that you load the script before the div with id `root`.

Comment: This was the reason. I was loading the script before the div. Thanks that solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with id `root` can't be found in the DOM because the script tag is before the div in the document. You could move the script tag after the div and it will work as expected.

```
<div id='root' data-link='https://x.com'></div>
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Dashboard(props) {
    return <h1>Hello, {props.link}</h1>;
}

const root = document.querySelector('#root')
ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard link={root.dataset.link} />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' data-link='https://x.com'></div>
```

It's totally workable, guess you might need to put some breakpoints and check if root has been passed correctly.